# Error in App.xaml.cs: System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'

Tags: uwp

I want to make an UWP page in singleton mode.
My solution's name is Singleton. And MainPage.xaml.cs is as below.

```
namespace Singleton
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        private static MainPage instance;

        private MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static MainPage Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new MainPage();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The MainPage.xaml code:

```
<Page
x:Class="Singleton.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Singleton"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>

</Grid>
```

But when I run the solution, it reports error in App.xaml.cs on below line:

```
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
```

Error message is:

```
System.MissingMethodException: 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message should be pretty self-explanatory. The framework cannot create an instance of the type `MainPage` and this is becasue you have made its constructor private.

Instead trying to navigate to the page based on its type, you could try to set the `Content` of the `Frame` to your singleton:

```
if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
{
    if (rootFrame.Content == null)
    {
        rootFrame.Content = MainPage.Instance;
    }
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Or you should consider whether it's actually good idea to define a page as a singleton.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It works. But using Navigate(), a parameter can be passed to it. While using your way, how to pass a parameter? @mm8

Comment: @TomXue: Not possible since you are not actually navigating to the page. But since it's singleton, you might as well simply set a property of the `MainPage`.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword defining MainPage contains partial, which means that the definition of MainPage is also included in other files. It is not advisable to create an instance of MainPage directly.

I suggest you change the code to the following:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public static MainPage instance;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        instance = this;
    }
}
```

This way you can still access the MainPage singleton from the outside.

Best regards.

Comment: "the MainPage singleton"? This suggestion effectively makes `MainPage` a non-singleton.

Comment: Sorry, my understanding of the singleton is wrong, I mean, access the created MainPage instance.